# change the order element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

Please refer below SVG.

```
<svg id="container_svg" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    <g id="container_svg_SeriesCollection" clip-path="url(#container_svg_ChartAreaClipRect)">
        <g id="container_svg_PanBtn" transform="translate(77,465)">
            <rect id="container_svg_PanRect" x="579.359375" y="-438" width="25" height="25" fill="#E5E5E5" stroke-width="1" stroke="#E5E5E5"><img width="25" height="25" href="../../Content/pan.gif" x="579.359375" y="-438" id="undefined" visibility="visible"></rect></g>
        <g id="rect"></g>
    </g>
    <g id="container_svg_AxisCrossToolTip"><rect id="container_svg_AxisToolTipRect_1" x="33" y="70.3984375" width="43.30859375" height="24" fill="white" stroke-width="1" stroke="Black"/><text id="container_svg_AxisToolTipText_1" x="38" y="82.39999389648438" fill="Black" font-size="12px" font-family="Times New Roman" font-style="Normal " text-anchor="start" dominant-baseline="middle">102.18</text></g>
</svg>
```

i want to change the order of the two groups -> "container_svg_PanBtn","rect" to last. i want to move these two groups as last in SVG in some condition.

```
if(condition)
{
//move 

"container_svg_PanBtn","rect" groups to last as always.
}
```

How can i do this in jquery ?

Is there something moveLast in jquery ?

Thanks,

Siva

Answer (score 2):

You can detach the element and append it to the end

```
$('#container_svg_PanBtn, #rect').detach().appendTo('#container_svg')
```